# WP Job Manager Category Drop-down; Change Placeholder Text Via Filter

Tags: plugins, functions, filters, array

I have been googling for hours with no really helpful outcome, I have a site that uses WP Job Manager. One of the search fields that comes with this plugin is a category drop-down list.

I would like to change the placeholder of this text from "Choose a category..." to "Choose your sectors..."

I came across this post: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/changing-placeholder-text-for-category-dropdown/

This explains it can be done.

The code below is taken from the WP Job Manager Plugin for reference with the above link.

```
function job_manager_dropdown_categories( $args = '' ) {
    $defaults = array(
        'orderby'         => 'id',
        'order'           => 'ASC',
        'show_count'      => 0,
        'hide_empty'      => 1,
        'child_of'        => 0,
        'exclude'         => '',
        'echo'            => 1,
        'selected'        => 0,
        'hierarchical'    => 0,
        'name'            => 'cat',
        'id'              => '',
        'class'           => 'job-manager-category-dropdown ' . ( is_rtl() ? 'chosen-rtl' : '' ),
        'depth'           => 0,
        'taxonomy'        => 'job_listing_category',
        'value'           => 'id',
        'multiple'        => true,
        'show_option_all' => false,
        'placeholder'     => __( 'Choose a category&hellip;', 'wp-job-manager' ),
        'no_results_text' => __( 'No results match', 'wp-job-manager' ),
        'multiple_text'   => __( 'Select Some Options', 'wp-job-manager' )
    );

    $r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

    if ( ! isset( $r['pad_counts'] ) && $r['show_count'] && $r['hierarchical'] ){
        $r['pad_counts'] = true;
    }

    // WPML & Polylang caching per language
    if ( defined( 'ICL_SITEPRESS_VERSION' ) ) {
        $r['lang'] = apply_filters( 'wpml_current_language', NULL );
    } elseif ( function_exists( 'pll_current_language' ) ) {
        $r['lang'] = pll_current_language();
    }

    extract( $r );

// Store in a transient to help sites with many cats
    $categories_hash = 'jm_cats_' . md5( json_encode( $r ) . WP_Job_Manager_Cache_Helper::get_transient_version( 'jm_get_' . $r['taxonomy'] ) );
    $categories      = get_transient( $categories_hash );

    if ( empty( $categories ) ) {
        $categories = get_terms( $taxonomy, array(
            'orderby'         => $r['orderby'],
            'order'           => $r['order'],
            'hide_empty'      => $r['hide_empty'],
            'child_of'        => $r['child_of'],
            'exclude'         => $r['exclude'],
            'hierarchical'    => $r['hierarchical']
        ) );
        set_transient( $categories_hash, $categories, DAY_IN_SECONDS * 30 );
    }

    $name       = esc_attr( $name );
    $class      = esc_attr( $class );
    $id         = $id ? esc_attr( $id ) : $name;

    $output = "<select name='" . esc_attr( $name ) . "[]' id='" . esc_attr( $id ) . "' class='" . esc_attr( $class ) . "' " . ( $multiple ? "multiple='multiple'" : '' ) . " data-placeholder='" . esc_attr( $placeholder ) . "' data-no_results_text='" . esc_attr( $no_results_text ) . "' data-multiple_text='" . esc_attr( $multiple_text ) . "'>\n";

    if ( $show_option_all ) {
        $output .= '<option value="">' . esc_html( $show_option_all ) . '</option>';
    }

    if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
        include_once( JOB_MANAGER_PLUGIN_DIR . '/includes/class-wp-job-manager-category-walker.php' );

        $walker = new WP_Job_Manager_Category_Walker;

        if ( $hierarchical ) {
            $depth = $r['depth'];  // Walk the full depth.
        } else {
            $depth = -1; // Flat.
        }

        $output .= $walker->walk( $categories, $depth, $r );
    }

    $output .= "</select>\n";

    if ( $echo ) {
        echo $output;
    }

    return $output;
}
```

I would appreciate any advice on how to create a filter to change the placeholder text.

Craig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the testing that I did, the placeholder string *Choose a category…* cannot be filtered with the `submit_job_form_fields` filter, but there are still ways to change that string.

One way to alter the text is to override the plugin's default `job-filters.php` template with your own.

Copy the default template, `/wp-job-manager/templates/job-filters.php` over to your theme: `/your-theme/job_manager/job-filters.php`

Edit your theme's copy of `job-filters.php` by adding the `placeholder` argument to both calls to `job_manager_dropdown_categories()`:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-job-manager-ajax-filters' ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'job_manager_job_filters_before', $atts ); ?>

<form class="job_filters">
    <?php do_action( 'job_manager_job_filters_start', $atts ); ?>

    <div class="search_jobs">
        <?php do_action( 'job_manager_job_filters_search_jobs_start', $atts ); ?>

        <div class="search_keywords">
            <label for="search_keywords"><?php _e( 'Keywords', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="search_keywords" id="search_keywords" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Keywords', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $keywords ); ?>" />
        </div>

        <div class="search_location">
            <label for="search_location"><?php _e( 'Location', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="search_location" id="search_location" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Location', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $location ); ?>" />
        </div>

        <?php if ( $categories ) : ?>
            <?php foreach ( $categories as $category ) : ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="search_categories[]" value="<?php echo sanitize_title( $category ); ?>" />
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php elseif ( $show_categories && ! is_tax( 'job_listing_category' ) && get_terms( 'job_listing_category' ) ) : ?>
            <div class="search_categories">
                <label for="search_categories"><?php _e( 'Category', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?></label>
                <?php if ( $show_category_multiselect ) : ?>
                    <?php job_manager_dropdown_categories( array( 'placeholder' => __( 'Choose a sector&hellip;', 'your-text-domain' ), 'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_category', 'hierarchical' => 1, 'name' => 'search_categories', 'orderby' => 'name', 'selected' => $selected_category, 'hide_empty' => false ) ); ?>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <?php job_manager_dropdown_categories( array( 'placeholder' => __( 'Choose a sector&hellip;', 'your-text-domain' ), 'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_category', 'hierarchical' => 1, 'show_option_all' => __( 'Any category', 'wp-job-manager' ), 'name' => 'search_categories', 'orderby' => 'name', 'selected' => $selected_category, 'multiple' => false ) ); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'job_manager_job_filters_search_jobs_end', $atts ); ?>
    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'job_manager_job_filters_end', $atts ); ?>
</form>

<?php do_action( 'job_manager_job_filters_after', $atts ); ?>

<noscript><?php _e( 'Your browser does not support JavaScript, or it is disabled. JavaScript must be enabled in order to view listings.', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?></noscript>
```

An alternative method of altering the *Choose a category…* text is to use the `gettext` filter:

```
add_filter('gettext', 'wpse243242_change_wp_job_manager_text', 20, 3 );
function wpse243242_change_wp_job_manager_text( $translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain ) {
    if ( 'wp-job-manager' !== $domain ) {
        return $translated_text;        
    }

    // make the changes to the text
    switch( $untranslated_text ) {
            // Multi category select
            case 'Choose a category&hellip;':
                $translated_text = __( 'Choose a sector&hellip;', 'text_domain' );
            break;

            // Single category select
            case 'Any category':
                $translated_text = __( 'Any sector', 'text_domain' );
            break;

            // add more items
     }

    return $translated_text;        
}
```

Comment: Dave you are a true life saver!